# How to search substring in QLatin1String?

Tags: c++, qt, substring, qstring

What is the reason that QLatin1String class has not any operations for searching substring in it, such as `indexOf`, `find` or `contains`? Only `startsWith` and `endsWith` I was found, but they can't search in the middle of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why, you'd have to take that up with Qt.

Generally speaking `QLatin1String` is used to indicate what we used to call ASCII text (no Unicode). `QString` is the default, all-powerful string in Qt, and you should generally use that, or you could convert it to a `std::string` and use that. Either of these may come at the cost of a copy.

If you want to avoid the copy, `QLatin1String` does have `begin()` and `end()` functions, so you can use standard algorithms on it too, like C++17's new `std::search()`:

```cpp
auto s = QLatin1String("The lazy dog");
auto needle = QLatin1String("azy");
auto it = std::search( std::begin(s), std::end(s), 
    std::boyer_moore_horspool_searcher( std::begin(needle), std::end(needle) ) );
```

Here's a working sample using `std::string`s that will also work for `QLatin1String`s on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cde0c02c293b957)</kbd>.

See more on [Bartek's coding blog](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/08/searchers.html).